# Accessing Object values without knowing the keys of that Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I did finish my tutorial for reactjs and start making an webapp which stores data in a json.I was able to find my object from a json data and the object would represent something like this one:

```
var data={
    name:<h1>Ram</h1>,
    description:<p>I want to be a Developer</p>,
    contact:<ul><li>66546464/li><li>66546464/li></ul>,
    DOB:<h4>23.05.2017</h4>
    }
```

I need to display in this way,but without using keys like

```
   {data.name or data.DOB}.
```

Output should be like this:

```
   <div>
       <h1>Ram</h1>
       <p>I want to be a Developer</p>
        <ul><li>66546464/li><li>66546464/li></ul>
        <h4>23.05.2017</h4>
    </div>
```

Is it possible to display the values without knowing the key? If so,please do help me?

Critics are always welcome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all properties values of a Javascript Object (without knowing the keys)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306669/how-to-get-all-properties-values-of-a-javascript-object-without-knowing-the-key)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!Can you please show me with  an example in react? That would be really helpful  @GuillaumeGeorges

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it in react.js

```
<div>
  {Object.keys(data).map(key) => (
    <span key={key}>
      {data[key]}
    </span>
  )}
</div>
```

An explanation. `Object.keys` takes all keys from your object, you map over them and for each one return a `<span>` ([note the key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)), and inside each span you take value from data by its key

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over keys of the object and append it's value as a children of parent div. Please consider below code:

```
<div>
  {Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key])}
</div>
```

`Object.keys` will give you keys of object and `map` function returns all the values of the key in a array format. It can be written in react JSX as shown in above code.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It makes more sense to store your data without the HTML tags (Storing with tags is bad practice, many frameworks/libraries will try to parse your special characters and cause you hassle down the road)
Then you can access the raw data in your view with keys.

`<h1>{data.name}</h1>
<p>{data.description}</p>`
etc

If you're solidly against using keys, you may find this thread on pretty printing JSON data to be of help:

[Pretty Printing JSON with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765163/pretty-printing-json-with-react)

Comment: Thanks for the headsup! I'll look into it  @Ryan