# How to loop over a json array and print the value without knowing the key in Ract Native?

Tags: json, react-native

Currently, I am using map to show the value with key name, but JSON will change dynamically so I won't be knowing the key for the JSON array. How to access it without knowing the key of the JSON?

My Json: (But the keys will be varying)

```
{
  "records": [{
      "DATE": "15/10/2020",
      "AMT": "103284",
      "TAX": "8958",
      "TOTAL": "112242"
    },
    {
      "DATE": "16/10/2020",
      "AMT": "2336",
      "TAX": "209",
      "TOTAL": "2545"
    }
  ]
}
```

Current code:

```
{
  sortedData && sortedData.length > 0 ?
    sortedData.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <View style={styles.container2}>
              <View style={styles.item}>
                <Text>{item.DATE}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.item2}>
                <Text>{item.AMT}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.item2}>
                <Text>{item.TAX}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.item2}>
                <Text>{item.TOTAL}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
          <Divider />
        </>
      );
    }) : false
}
```

I tried the below code
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Object values without knowing the keys of that Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933104/accessing-object-values-without-knowing-the-keys-of-that-objects)

Comment: I tried the first answer to the question that you mentioned, but syntax error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object.keys will give you keys of object and map function returns all the values of the key in a array format.

```
{Object.keys(sortedData).map(key => sortedData[key])}
```

This might help

```
<div>
  {arr.map(obj =>
    Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => (
      <tr key={key}>
        <td>Key: {key}</td>
        <td>Activity Type: {value.activityType}</td>
        <td>DurationInSeconds: {value.durationInSeconds}</td>
      </tr>
    )))}
</div>
```

Comment: I am not able to use view inside the loop instead of sortedData[key] which you are using inside

Comment: the second loop is printing 4 times because there is 4 keys in each row

Comment: Yes exactly, you can achieve your desired output with this?

Comment: yes, I modified the code little bit and working fine